# Firmware Update Canon EOS 80D

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, firmware

Following the proper instructions, I'm using a formatted SD card (64gb) with the latest firmware update (1.0.3; for the Canon EOS80D) downloaded in the root directory (I believe.) When I inset the card into the camera, turn it on, and go to the firmware page in the camera itself. Upon clicking the firmware, I am told that there needs to be a memory card inserted with the update on it in order to update the camera's firmware. I am unsure as to what I am doing wrong here. Is my SD card too large?

Comment: Did you format the SD card in the camera?

Comment: Did you extract the .FIR file from the .zip download? Or did you copy the .zip archive to the card?

Comment: What means "downloaded in the root directory (I believe.)": Did you, or didn't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility: The .pdf instructions contained in the download says that the SD card should be 64MB or more up to 128GB or less. So the size of your 64GB card should not be an issue, but the card may have some other problem.

You can try another SD card up to 128GB to see if the card is the issue.

Also note that if you have the card partitioned in any way, it probably won't work to update the firmware.

Another possibility: If you did the fresh format using your computer, try formatting the card in the camera. Then copy the .FIR file you extracted from the .zip file you downloaded to the card's root directory.

- DO NOT place it inside the DCIM folder or any other folder on the card. Place it directly to the card.
- DO NOT copy the .zip file to the card. Extract the contents of the .zip file on your computer and only copy the 80D00103.FIR file to the root directory of the SD card.

The contents of the card should look like this (your drive letter will probably be different, depending on how many other drives there are connected to your computer.):

[image]

Comment: It would appear the issue I was facing was copying both of the files from the extracted zip file and placing them on the card. When I only copied over the 80D00103.FIR file, it worked. Thanks, mate!